# php query between operator

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

```
$eredmeny = mysql_query("SELECT t_nev, sum(t_ertek)
    FROM `termek_mozgas`
    WHERE datum BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
        AND muv_1 = 'Beszerzés'
        OR muv_1 = 'Göngyöleg vissza'
        OR muv_1 = 'Gyártásból bejövő' group by t_nev ");
```

Hy! Thanks the help! My problem is my query isn't working good.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working good"? Do you get the desired result - if not, what is it? It is hard to help you without knowing what is wrong

Comment: Consider braces to ensure that your combination of AND or OR criteria are being evaluated correctly

Comment: `mysql_query` has been deprecated for a while now.  Stop using it, or stop expecting help with using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$eredmeny = mysql_query("SELECT t_nev, sum(t_ertek)
    FROM `termek_mozgas`
    WHERE datum BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
        AND
( muv_1 = 'Beszerzés'
        OR muv_1 = 'Göngyöleg vissza'
        OR muv_1 = 'Gyártásból bejövő'
)
 group by t_nev ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `WHERE` condition like below and also use `IN` operator instead of multiple chained `OR` condition

```
   WHERE datum BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
   AND muv_1 IN ('Beszerzés',
                 'Göngyöleg vissza',
                 'Gyártásból bejövő')
```